# PyQt Label not changing text

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, pyqt, label

I have this code running on a PyQt window on windows:

```
    try:
        self.actorUser.findIdfFiles(pathToFolder)
        msg = "Processando arquivos..."
        self.processingLabel.setText(msg)

        self.actorUser.runSimulation(pathToFolder, pathToEpw)
```

Inside the "runSimulation" code I start a subprocess using the method "call". This blocks my GUI and at the title of the window appears "Python stopping responding", but if I wait a little bit the subprocess finishes normally, and the label is finally changed. But what I want is that the label have is text really changed before the subprocess started. What can I do??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qt (and most UI frameworks) don't update the display as soon as values are set, only when they are told to repaint.

What you need to do is add a call

```
QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()
```

before your long-running subprocess, to make it process all pending events.

Answer (score 1):

Joe P 's answer is quite right.
But this method is change to

```
QtCore.QCoreApplication.processEvents()
```

in pyqt5

link: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents

Comment: QApplication is inherits from QCoreApplication so it is still possible to call QApplication.processEvents. "(QCoreApplication) is used by non-GUI applications to provide their event loop. ... For GUI applications, see QGuiApplication. For applications that use the Qt Widgets module, see QApplication."